# How to give two GameObjects references to each other?

Tags: unity, c#, architecture

I have two GameObjects and would like both to have a reference to the other.  I know this can be done by creating public properties and setting them with Unity's inspector, but my preference is to stay in code whenever possible.  Something like this:

```
public class Object1 : MonoBehavior
{
    private Object2 _object2;

    public void Start()
    {
        _object2 = GetComponent<Object2>();
    }
}

public class Object2 : MonoBehavior
{
    private Object1 _object1;

    public void Start()
    {
        _object1 = GetComponent<Object1>();
    }
}
```

I understand this doesn't work because one Start has to run before the other, but I'm not sure what alternative would be the best from a code quality standpoint.

- I could refactor so Object2 doesn't have a reference to Object1, but then it can't call any functions on Object1.  Instead, Object1 would have to constantly query Object2 for whether or not it should do something.
- I could get the other component in Update rather than Start, but that seems like a bad strategy from a performance standpoint - searching for an object every frame even though it's always the same object.
- I could solve it outside of Start / Update.  For example, Object2 could have a SetObject1 function that Object1 calls, or an EventManager could be used to communicate between objects.  This seems like it might be a tad overkill for something as commonplace as this.

Are any of these a common practice among Unity devs?  Is there another option I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't run? There shouldn't be a problem for calling both at the start. But you can add a `while (_object1 == null)` before `_object1 = GetComponent<Object1>();`

Comment: And another thing, what `object1` is? the name says it's a game object but the code says it's a component

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It looks like the code does indeed run now - I screwed up elsewhere producing the null references and assumed this pair of Starts was the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand this doesn't work because one Start has to run before the other.

No, it **does** work. Even if the two `Start()` functions execute one after another, the Components they are referencing already exist. You can test it for yourself by adding `Debug.Log(_objectX)` after using `GetComponent<>()`.

> Object1 would have to constantly query Object2 for whether or not it should do something.

This is called *polling* and it's perfectly fine, especially if you want to decrease [interdependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) among your classes and entities. Alternatively, you can expose some [events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html) and invoke callbacks accordingly.

> I could get the other component in Update but that seems like a bad strategy.

Yes, it is.

> I could solve it outside of Start / Update.

Unity encourages using [`Awake()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) for script referencing rather than `Start()`. This way, when `Start()` executes, all your scripts own a working reference regardless of their execution order.

> An EventManager could be used to communicate between objects.

It would also help you avoid mutual references among objects. The EventManager may expose UnityEvents that trigger ObjectX's callbacks when needed.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I made a mistake elsewhere and misinterpreted the problem.  Thanks for that + all this other information.  I'll be sure to use Awake from here on.